# Encrypt data using js

Tags: javascript, encryption

Is it **possible/viable** to encrypt data using Java-Script before sending it to a request?

If so, you have any example on how to do it safely?

Comment: js can encrypt about as well as any other language, but it depends on what you mean by encryption as far as examples go. i like private key schemes like AES, which are VERY secure, but  require pre-transfer coordination of the private keys...

Comment: I just emphasized the point asked in the OP "possible/viable". However adding a scenario of the use could actually make the question very specific. It looks very generic now and face the risk of closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what type of encryption is required. You may refer Crypto.js (https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for some details.

Comment: People always pick the obvious answer. I know data must be encrypted on Server Side, i just ask if its possible to do with js. Thank you for your answer, it will be the best answer here to me

Comment: @Carlos: Why don't you add a specific scenario for your use? That will add value to the question.

Comment: its a js based browser game, just for study purposes. It will receive and send character status by json. I need encrypt or encode data so  the player wont be able to modify it

Answer (score 3):

Scenario: client turns off javascript.

Suddenly your encryption is worthless. Always encrypt server side!

Comment: if the app uses js to upload then it's the app that the user breaks, not the security...

Comment: If the user can break the app, that's probably a serious security flaw. When a break happens, it means there's a probably exploit.

Comment: i meant the user breaks the app by turning off js like you said, which should not expose security flaws... if they can't send without JS, or even boot the app, they won't be by-passing anything.  by requiring JS, we don't have to worry about non-js behavior.

Answer (score 1):

encrypting on javascript is not something you would do. it is something that is done on client's browser and if user can see how it is encrypted then encrypting it wouldnt make sense.

Comment: how would the user seeing encryption details have any bearing on the  effectiveness of encryption?

Comment: encryption is used to hide details from being exposed. if someone can reverse it then it doesnt help.
What exactly is that you are looking for and may be i can answer it better.